# I am getting error while using React-app first time, Error is core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

**I am trying to create-react-app but getting stuck again and again here only,
I had already work around it, like I uninstalled the node.js and then again reinstalled that one, but only package.json and my-app folder got created. No src/or another folder as requiring got created.**

terminal outcome-

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\user\Desktop\Attainu\Sumit-malviya-au8\coding-challenges\week09\demo\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\user\Desktop\Attainu\Sumit-malviya-au8\coding-challenges\week09\demo\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> **core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\user\Desktop\Attainu\Sumit-malviya-au8\coding-challenges\week09\demo\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"**

- cra-template@1.0.3
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
  **added 1602 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1606 packages in 736.792s**

59 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

after running npm audit fix.

```
$ npm audit fix
npm WARN user@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, not sure why is happens but the cmd.exe keep getting suspended. Possible that your anit-virus software may also be stopping something.

Try:

1. Run - npx create-react-app my-app
2. Open Resource Monitor
3. If the command has a status of suspended - right click and 'resume process'

The dependencies will then be installed.